# Comparing bit representation of objects in Python

Tags: python, hash, bit

I am watching a video named [The Mighty Dictionary](https://youtu.be/C4Kc8xzcA68?t=166) which has the following code:

```
k1 = bits(hash('Monty'))
k2 = bits(hash('Money'))
diff = ('^' [a==b] for a,b in zip(k1,k2))
print(k1,k2,''.join(diff))
```

As I understand, `bits` is not a built-in method in Python, but his own written method which is similar to `format(x, 'b'), or is it something that existed in Python 2? (I've never wrote code in Python 2)

I've tried to accomplish the same, get the bits representation of the strings and check where the bits differ:

```
k1 = format(hash('Monty'),'b')
k2 = format(hash('Money'),'b')
diff = ('^ ' [a==b] for a,b in zip(k1,k2))
print(k1,'\n',k2,'\n',''.join(diff))
```

I do get the expected result:

**UPDATED**
Had to shift the first line by 1 space to match the symbols

```
 110111010100001110100101100000100110111111110001001101111000110 
 -1000001111101001011101001010101101000111001011011000011110100 
 ^  ^^^  ^ ^^ ^^^   ^^^^^^^ ^ ^^^^^  ^^   ^^  ^^^^^^^ ^   ^ ^^^
```

Also, the lengths of the bits are not the same, whereas I understand that no matter the string, it will take the same, in my case, 64 bits? But its 63 and 62.

```
print(len(format(hash('Monty'),'b')))
print(len(format(hash('Money'),'b')))

63
62
```

So, to sum up my question:

1. Is `bits` a built-in method in Python2?
2. Is the recommended way to compare bit representation of an object is using the following:

```
def fn():
    pass

print(format(hash(fn),'b'))
# -111111111111111111111111111111111101111000110001011100000000101
```

3. Shouldn't all objects have the same length of bits that represent the object depending on the processor? If I run the following code several times I get these results:

```
def fn():
    pass

def nf():
    pass

print(format(hash(fn),'b'))
print(format(hash(nf),'b'))

# first time
# 10001001010011010111110000100
# -111111111111111111111111111111111101110110101100101000001000001

# second time
# 10001001010011010111111101010
# 10001001010011010111110000100

# third time
# 10001001010011010111101010001
# -111111111111111111111111111111111101110110101100101000001000001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, `bits` is not a built-in function in Python 2 or Python 3.
2. By default `format()` doesn't show leading zeroes. Use the format string `032b` to format the number in a 32-character field with leading zeroes.

```
>>> format(hash('Monty'), '032b')
'1001000100011010010110101101101011000010101011100110001010001'
```

Another problem you're running into is that `hash()` can return negative numbers. Maybe this couldn't happen in Python 2, or his `bits()` function shows the two's complement bits of the number. You can do this by normalizing the input:

```
def bits(n):
    if n < 0:
        n = 2**32 + n
    return format(n, '032b')
```

3. Every time you run the code, you define new `fn` and `nf` functions. Different functions will not necessarily have the same hash code, even if they have the same name.

If you don't redefine the functions, you should get the same hash codes each time.

Hashing strings and numbers just depends on the contents, but hashing more complex objects depends on the specific instance.